# WooCommerce Product Search Error

Tags: categories, errors, plugins

I wanted to display product category,in product catalog on my WooCommerce site.I asked another question earlier to make this code working.I added this code on my content-product.php file.

```
    <?php
   $term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );
   $parents = get_the_terms($term->parent, get_query_var('taxonomy') );

   echo "<div class='product-cat'>";
   echo "In"." "." ";
   foreach( $parents as $parent ) {
   echo '<a href="'.get_term_link($parent).'">'.$parent->name.'</a>';
    }
  echo "</div>";
  ?>
```

Everything is working perfectly on product catalog,but whenever i do a search i am getting this error " Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" .

I am not that good with programming,i managed make the code working for product catalogs but it is not working with search.Please if anyone can help me,it will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`" Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" .` means that the `$parents` variable is not an array so you can't loop through it.  You should wrap the `foreach` loop in an `if` check that verifies that `$parents` is something valid.

```
<?php
   $term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );
   $parents = get_the_terms($term->parent, get_query_var('taxonomy') );

   if( $parents && ! is_wp_error($parents) ) :

     echo "<div class='product-cat'>";
     echo "In"." "." ";
     foreach( $parents as $parent ) {
      echo '<a href="'.get_term_link($parent).'">'.$parent->name.'</a>';
     }
     echo "</div>";

   endif;

?>
```

Though secondarily.... `get_query_var('term')` and `get_query_var('taxonomy')` are not returning anything on the search page because those query vars don't pertain to the search query.

Comment: Thanks for answering,can you tell me which functions should i use for search page instead get_query_var().

Comment: That depends. I can't really tell what you are trying to do. Could you edit your question?